Lunar capture simulation
So I'm trying to simulate the Apollo 11 mission and I'm kinda stuck. I've set the origin of my coordinate system to be in Earth's center of mass and was able to complete a gravity turn to get into Earths orbit and a translunar injection to get to the Moon. Those trajectories look fine to me. I'm stuck at trying to enter the Moon's orbit. From my understanding, to enter orbit I have to have the proper orbital velocity for that altitude and enter at a 90 degree angle (angle between the rocket velocity vector and a vector going out radially from the Moon's center to the rocket's position). If my coordinate system's origin is in Earth's center of mass, the moon radial vector I'm looking for is:
$$
\textbf{r} = \textbf{r}_{rocket} - \textbf{r}_{moon}, 
$$
where $\textbf{r}_{rocket}$ is the latest position vector of the rocket and $\textbf{r}_{moon}$ is the latest position of the Moon's center of mass. Using the scalar product I found that the angle between the velocity vector and the radial position vector was too big, around 100 degrees. I set the code up to use thrust to adjust the angle and the value of the velocity and at an altitude of 150 km the angle is $90.0347$ degrees and the velocity $1612.33 \: \text{m}/\text{s}$. I've calculated the orbital velocity to be $v_{orbital}(150\: \text{km}) = 1611 \: \text{m}/\text{s}$. Both the Moon and the rocket are moving, so every time step $dt$ (in the descent to 150 km) I'm updating $\textbf{r}_{moon}$, $\textbf{r}_{rocket}$, and recalculating $\textbf{r}\cdot\textbf{v}$. Once the rocket reaches orbital velocity and entry angle, I turn off the thrust. Despite this the rocket doesn't get into any kind of orbit, it just gets kinda slingshot. The pictures for reference.
Last velocity vector before turning thrust off: $\textbf{v} = 1591.86\:\hat{\textbf{x}} -256.076\:\hat{\textbf{y}}$. And the last position vector $\textbf{r} = 298877 \:\hat{\textbf{x}} + 1865140\:\hat{\textbf{y}}$. The trajectory on the last image looks a bit off honestly, but I can't really pinpoint the problem. I hope I gave you enough information. The simulation depicts the time frame of 5 days.

Are you calculating the appropriate orbital velocity vector in the Earth frame or the Moon frame? I.e. when you say it should be 1611m/s, is that relative to the centre of the Moon?

@MariusLadegårdMeyer That is relative to the Moon, yes.

Oh, I didn't transform the velocity. I was working with the vector from Earth's frame. That is the error?

For terrestrial orbits, it's better to use the EMB (Earth-Moon Barycentre), not the centre of the Earth. See these ISS distance plots, produced using data from JPL Horizons: https://i.sstatic.net/zOdMFc75.png & https://i.sstatic.net/QsXQEbSn.png (3 minute timestep, using the Terrestrial Time scale, not UTC).

@TiredStudent that's at least one possible error. Hard to say if there are more errors without seeing code, but that looks like a job for your TA as we don't do code review here.
